# EE1 - Copy Field Groups to another site in MSM or use them in another site template?

Tags: multi-site-manager, ee1, field-group

I need to copy a page to another segment in a site both in MSM on 1.6.8. I was just calling the

```
site="first-site"
```

from the second site template and using the info that way. The problem is that the markets have now separated direction. They want the same "page" only with different content and style. (lol)

There are a lot of fields and I would like to just copy the field group and possible the entry over to the other site being that the entry options will remain the same.

Any ideas? Besides just database manipulation...

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered in the comments above...

I ended up copying the db out and re-upping the DB to a single site (new requirement added), then pulling everything out that ws with site_id of the other sites, changing the site_id of the site needed, and running with it that way. As for the fields, I kept the fields needed from the original site and changed the site_id number to match the new config and all sub tables related.

I will write this up when I get some time. (still buried)

Answer (score 1):

MSM offers you the option to copy or move over field groups and content when you first create a new site if memory serves, but that is a one time offer, which it seems like it is unlikely to help you now, EXCEPT:

If you dig into the MSM code that handles that part of things it would make it a lot easier for you to work out the queries that you'd need to do it directly in the database.

Here is a starting point:

In cp.sites.php is a function called `new_site_form`, in that function is a section demarcated by a comment:

```
/**  New Site?  Allow Moving/Copying of Existing Data
```

That has the code that does the interface providing those options

in the function `update_site` is a comment:

```
/**  Moving of Data?
```

That appears to be the logic that actually moves the stuff.

I'm short on time so that's as far as I can take it, but hopefully it gives you a boost.

Comment: Yeah... The sites are already created and entangled....

I ended up copying the db out and re-upping the DB to a single site (new requirement added), then pulling everything out that ws with site_id of the other sites, changing the site_id of the site needed, and running with it that way.

As for the fields, I kept the fields needed from the original site and changed the site_id number to match the new config and all sub tables related.

No fun!!!   :(

Comment: I'm glad you got it worked out. It may be a good idea to write this up as an answer in greater detail.

Comment: I will when I get caught up a bit.... I just got landslid.   ;)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't MSM offer to duplicate templates and field groups for you when you create a new site? I think this was true under the 1.6.8 version as well as now. I just can't recall. But you can always test it under a test site. That way, you'll have should end up with everything you need, then just adjust the templates as needed.